# Module action returns 404

Tags: magento-1.9, module, controllers, ce-1.9.2.4, admin-controller

I am making a module that adds a button to the Admin order view and allows the user to create a shipment and invoice (among others) once this button is clicked.

I have used an observer to add the button and get the current order_id. I also used setLocation to the onclick parameter of the button.

However, when I press the button, I am presented with a 404 page. I am not sure if the problem is my controller, setLocation url or somthing else. Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <ID_AcsCourier>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ID_AcsCourier>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <acscourier>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>ID_AcsCourier</module>
                <frontName>acscourier</frontName>
            </args>
        </acscourier>
    </routers>
</frontend>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <id_acscourier before="Mage_Adminhtml">ID_AcsCourier_Adminhtml</id_acscourier>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<global>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
            <observers>
                <acscourier>
                    <class>ID_AcsCourier_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addButtonVoucher</method>
                </acscourier>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
    </events>

    <helpers>
        <acscourier>
            <class>ID_AcsCourier_Helper</class>
        </acscourier>
    </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

And this is the button onclick from my observer:.

```
'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\' '  . Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/acscourier/index', array('order' => $order['order_id'])) . '\')',
```

My controller (**AcsCourierController.php**) is under *controllers/Adminhtml* and begins like this:

```
class ID_AcsCourier_Adminhtml_AcsCourierController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction() {
        echo "Hello World";
        exit;
    }

}
```

Again, this module is not supposed to produce any output. Once it completes, it will just redirect back to the order page and (hopefully) present a message. But in order to get there, I first need to sort the 404 thing...

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL `*/acscourier/index` points to an `AcscourierController.php` file (no uppercase C).

The solution is either to rename your controller file (and class name) to `AcscourierController` or to change your URL to `*/acs_courier/index`

Also I suggest respecting the case in your `config.xml` by replacing:

```
    <adminhtml>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <id_acscourier before="Mage_Adminhtml">ID_AcsCourier_Adminhtml</id_acscourier>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </adminhtml>
```

With:

```
    <adminhtml>
        <args>
            <modules>
                <ID_AcsCourier before="Mage_Adminhtml">ID_AcsCourier_Adminhtml</ID_AcsCourier>
            </modules>
        </args>
    </adminhtml>
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed this... I have been looking at anything else except case! Sometimes I just forget how much Magento loves its case :-P

Comment: @swiss_blade yeah unfortunately it's easy to miss. My recommendation is to avoid camelcase in module and file name as much as possible